# How can I modify app async storage outside of the iOS App

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I recently factory reset my old iOS phone. I migrated everything to a new iOS phone via iCloud Backups. However, the data in async storage in one of my apps didn't get migrated over because `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage` disables async storage backup to iCloud by default.

I would like to set some values in async storage without launching the app, e.g. I want to set the flag "secretFeatureEnabled" to "true". The ["Where your data is stored"](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/advanced/where_data_stored) part of the doc states

> ios - small values (not exceeding 1024 characters) are serialized and stored in a common manifest.json file, while larger values are stored in individual, dedicated files (named as MD5 hashed key)

Where can I find these files and how do I create these files such that I can set the key-value without going into the app?

Comment: AFAIK this won’t be possible.